# Stored Procedure Date time error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote an sp basically to check the diff between dates If the diff is either 4 or 2 then the sp runs and raises an error it not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AML_DATECHECK
 @ALERTDAY VARCHAR
 AS
IF((SELECT "DAY_DESC" =  
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(VARCHAR,"BUSINESS_DAY",120),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(VARCHAR,'@ALERTDAY',121),120))=  4 
      THEN 'BUSINESS DAY IS FRIDAY'
      WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(VARCHAR,"BUSINESS_DAY",120),
      CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),'@ALERTDAY',121),120)) = 2 
      THEN  'BUSINESS DAY IS' + datename(dw,"BUSINESS_DAY")  
      END
FROM [US_AML_APP].[dbo].[SAM_APP_USER_PROCESS] WHERE
 [PROCESS_NAME]='AML_SAM_dailyProcess') IS NULL )
     RAISERROR('DATE CHECK FAILED',11,1)
     ELSE
     RAISERROR('DATE CHECK PASSED',12,2)
     RETURN
```

When I try to pass a parameter like here

```
exec AML_DATECHECK @ALERTDAY='2015-11-23'
```

it fails.

I have also tried all the date formats such as 2015/23/11 and tried giving all the datatypes but the execution fails with:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Why put variable parameter between quotation marks??, and try to convert string's like 'BUSINESS_DAY" ??.

Comment: if I remove the quotes too, its throwing the same error juan and I am converting the business to date a difference  such that if the difference is 4 or 2 then the SP should run fine

Comment: Can you please provide table schema and data example in SQLFiddle?

Comment: table has columns like process_name , is_active , business_day , businessdayinc,bus_dayunit data types for which are varchar, tinyint , datetime , int, varchar(50) respectively and the table has only 19 records, for which the date gets updated as soon as the alert generation is completed